missing of continuum states: insufficiency of CI?
As far as I know, the configuration-interaction scheme is simple. It simply expand the many-electron eigenstate with respect to a basis, which is often a set of Slater determinants built of some orthonormal single-particle orbitals.
The problem is, while in principle, one has to take a complete set of single particle basis, one often simply take only the single-particle bound states, or even a finite subset of the bound states.
I suspect that because we give up the single-particle continuum states, the CI will never converge to the many-electron exact eigenvalues, even if we take all the single-particle bound states.
Is this true?
